# Hypothesis class with n elements that shatters a set C of n/2 points

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension, pac-learning

I started learning Advanced Machine Learning and came across a problem that stuck. I would be grateful if you could help me with some ideas or solutions:

What is the maximum value of the natural even number $n$, $n=2m$, such that there exists a hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ with $n$ elements that shatters a set C of $m = \frac{n}{2}$ points?  Give an example of such $\mathcal{H}$ and C.

Thanks!